# how to use proxy in cefSharp ver 100? when i use proxy i see blank page

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I use CefSharp version 100 in WinForms.
This is my code snippet

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;
public CefSettings settings;
string main_site = "https://whatismyipaddress.com";

    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }
public void InitBrowser()
        {
            settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "165.225.208.96:10605");
            settings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
            //CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new ProxyOptions(ip: "165.225.208.96", port: "10605");

            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(main_site);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chrome);
            chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            chrome.MenuHandler = new DevToolsMenuHandler(); 
            chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
            chrome.LifeSpanHandler = new MyCustomLifeSpanHandler(); 
        }
```

it works fine without proxy, but when i use proxy i get blank page
I also tried to use

```
CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new ProxyOptions(ip: "165.225.208.96", port: "10605");
```

but i get also blank page

I found code snippet below, but i dont know hot to use this in my code,
maybe its what i need? please help

```
            Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate {
                var rc = chrome.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
                var v = new Dictionary<string,
                    object>();
                v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";
                v["server"] = "185.24.233.208:80";
                string error;
                bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);
            });
```

Comment: Does the same proxy work in Chrome? Check the log file for errors see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: Yes, the same proxy work in Chrome, but there is nothing in the log file

Comment: from 30 attempting of launch 1 or 2 time was successful and there were few logs in log file

Comment: [0415/150413.177:INFO:CONSOLE(524)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined", source: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ (524)

[0415/150415.433:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "OneSignal: Using fallback ES5 Stub for backwards compatibility.", source: https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js (1)

[0415/150418.073:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Fusebox Player loading error: Failed to fetch", source: https://app.fusebox.fm/embed/player.js (2)

[0415/150418.952:INFO:CONSOLE(246)] "USP is not accessible", source: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ (246)

Comment: Amaitland, sir please help me

Comment: Please be patient, I will answer when time permits. How are you testing in Chrome? I'd suggest testing using the same command line argument with chrome. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-proxy-resolution